# rackspace cloudfiles throws ContainerNotFoundException after migration from jclouds 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: java, rackspace, cloudfiles, jclouds

I am trying to update the jclouds libs we use from version 1.5 to 1.7.

We access the api the following way:
https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudfiles

```
private RestContext<CommonSwiftClient, CommonSwiftAsyncClient> swift;
BlobStoreContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(PROVIDER)
.credentials(username, apiKey)
.buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);

swift = context.unwrap();
```

RestContext is deprecated since 1.6.
http://demobox.github.io/jclouds-maven-site-1.6.0/1.6.0/jclouds-multi/apidocs/org/jclouds/rest/RestContext.html

I tried to get it working this way:

```
ContextBuilder contextBuilder = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(rackspaceProvider)
.credentials(rackspaceUsername, rackspaceApiKey);
rackspaceApi = contextBuilder.buildApi(CloudFilesClient.class);
```

At runtime, uploading a file i get the following error:

```
org.jclouds.blobstore.ContainerNotFoundException
```

The examples in the jclouds github project seem to use the deprecated approach (Links mentioned above).

Any ideas how to solve this? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the container that you're uploading into exist? The `putObject` method doesn't automatically create the container that you name if it doesn't exist; you need to call `createContainer` explicitly to create it, first.

Here's an example that creates a container and uploads a file into it:

```
CloudFilesClient client = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("cloudfiles-us")
    .credentials(USERNAME, APIKEY)
    .buildApi(CloudFilesClient.class);

client.createContainer("sample");

SwiftObject object = client.newSwiftObject();
object.getInfo().setName("somefile.txt");
object.setPayload("file or bytearray or something else here");
client.putObject("sample", object);

// ...

client.close();
```

You're right that the examples in `jclouds-examples` still reference `RestClient`, but you should be able to translate to the new style by substituting your `rackspaceApi` object where they call `swift.getApi()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The container exists - I forgot to mention that.
When I created a new container it worked perfect.
I still get the ContainerNotFoundException if I try to access the existing container.